# Keeping history of branch after merging

Tags: git

Sorry, Git beginner here. I have two branches, `feature` and `first-feature`. I do 10 commits in `first-feature` and then merge everything back over to `feature`. I am wondering, which of the following two scenarios is most common for a Git workflow or if one of them is even wrong?

A) Do the 10 commits of `first-feature` show up in the history of `feature` as well

or

B) `feature` has only a single commit which represents the new feature?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specify explicitly, the commits will not be squashed.

So

```
git checkout feature
git merge first-feature
git push
```

will copy the individual commits

whereas

```
git checkout feature
git merge --squash first-feature
git push
```

will create a single merge commit.

In general squashing is recommended to keep the commit history clean.

Comment: The last sentence made the difference. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielStephens "Clean history" is in the eye of the beholder. /In general squashing is recommended/ is not a good advice. You should obey your project's policy whether you squash or not. In projects, where I have authority, squashing is forbidden, because it has zero advantages (in my eyes).

Answer (score 2):

When merging two branches, `git merge` preserve all commits made to the merged branch, unless you use the `squash flag`. For example, if you have a `feature branch` and it has 3 commits when you merge that to the `master`, all of those commits will show on the `master branch` history and it will appear as if those commits were written on top of `master branch` all along.

#### Edit:

Preserving history has some pros to it:

> - It allows you to preserve the commit history for any given feature while not worrying about overriding commits and changing history. It helps you avoid unnecessary git reverts or resets!
> - Different features remain isolated and don't interfere with existing commit histories.
> - Can help you re-integrate a completed feature branch.

On the other hand, if you value more a clean, linear history then `git rebase` or the `squash flag` may be most appropriate. You will avoid unnecessary commits and keep changes more centralized and linear!

Comment: Thanks! I just found `squash` to "remove/hide" them. Is the scenario you described more common or why would I be interested in the history of the development of the feature?